# click event of child not triggered

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**html**:

```
<div id="schemeView" class="view" style="margin-top: 0px; opacity: 1; z-index: 1;">
    <ul>
        <li class="scheme-color" style="width:16.666666666666668%"> 
            <div class="card" style="background:#288dff">
                <span class="card-value">#288dff</span> 
            </div> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS**:

```
#schemeView {
    position: absolute;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#schemeView ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.scheme-color {
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
div.card {
    background: #288dff;
    width: 90%;
    height: 80%;
    margin-left: 5%;]
}
span.card-value {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    background: rgba(243,243,243,.75);
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
    color: #555;
    font-family: Monaco,Courier,monospace;
}
div.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 20px 30px #777;
}
```

**JS**:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.scheme-color').click(function() {
      alert('hi')
    });
});
```

**What it should do**:

- every time i click an `li` element, it will alert `'hi'`

**What it's doing**:

- absolutely nothing when i click an `li`
- when i change
  `.scheme-color` to `#schemeView ul` it works perfectly but if i use
  `#schemeView ul li` it does nothing

> I suspect it has something to do with the styling rules of the unordered list and its content

Comment: li has invalid markup inside it i.e. div

Comment: Are you adding any of the content after the page loads?

Comment: Your code is absolutely working fine, i tested in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nthhpbr7/).

Comment: Works fine, you sure your JS is included? Any error in console that are preventing it from getting executed?

Comment: @Bhojendra-C-LinkNepal: The markup is valid.

Comment: Based on that `z-index: -1` I'm guessing this is a collision with something else on the page covering it up. The self-contained example forks fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine. But, if you're **adding the target content after the page loads, use event delegation** as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#schemeView').on('click', '.scheme-color', function() {
        alert('hi')
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#schemeView').on('click', '.scheme-color', function() {
      alert('hi')
    });
});
```

```css
#schemeView {
    position: absolute;
    background: #f7f7f7;
    top: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
#schemeView ul {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-top: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}
.scheme-color {
    height: 100%;
    max-width: 400px;
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-top: 5%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
div.card {
    background: #288dff;
    width: 90%;
    height: 80%;
    margin-left: 5%;]
}
span.card-value {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 35px;
    background: rgba(243,243,243,.75);
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 15px;
    color: #555;
    font-family: Monaco,Courier,monospace;
}
div.card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 20px 30px #777;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="schemeView" class="view" style="margin-top: 0px; opacity: 1; z-index: 1;">
    <ul>
        <li class="scheme-color" style="width:16.666666666666668%"> 
            <div class="card" style="background:#288dff">
                <span class="card-value">#288dff</span> 
            </div> 
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It does work with `$('.scheme-color')`. Run the below snippet:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.scheme-color').click(function() {
    alert('hi')
  });
});
```

```css
#schemeView {
  position: absolute;
  background: #f7f7f7;
  top: 0;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 0;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
#schemeView ul {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.scheme-color {
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 400px;
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 5%;
  cursor: pointer;
}
div.card {
  background: #288dff;
  width: 90%;
  height: 80%;
  margin-left: 5%;
  ]
}
span.card-value {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 35px;
  background: rgba(243, 243, 243, .75);
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 15px;
  color: #555;
  font-family: Monaco, Courier, monospace;
}
div.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 20px 30px #777;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="schemeView" class="view" style="margin-top: 0px; opacity: 1; z-index: 1;">
  <ul>
    <li class="scheme-color" style="width:16.666666666666668%">
      <div class="card" style="background:#288dff">
        <span class="card-value">#288dff</span> 
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```